# How to load an html into another html without security warnings

Tags: javascript, html

I'm loading (locally) an html into another html using jquery's load command.

However I'm getting the:
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://path/newcontent.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.**

newcontent.html:

```
<div>
New Content
</div>
```

index.html

```
<div id='putnewcontenthere'>
</div>
```

I'm using this command:

```
$("#putnewcontenthere").load("newcontent.html", function() {
          //load was performed
        });
```

Now I'm doing this locally without a webserver AND I want to be able to do this "safely" without security warnings AND I don't want to start chrome with disabling security.

I don't need to necessarily use this 'load' command. If there's any other 'hack' my ears are open to any ideas. I'd just like it to work similarly but without security warnings.

Basically, I have a file (locally) and this index.html file is an application that has many screens. I can basically put EVERYTHING into my .html file (and hide/show divs), but I don't want to do this. I want to have a different .html for each one of my screens and load it into the main file programmatically. Is it possible?

(Also, I don't want to use javascript and put my htmls into a string mainly because I want these various htmls to be easily editable.)

Any suggestions?

**NOTE: I can't use this as a webserver b/c I'm using this in a Phonegap App which isn't a webserver it's simply static content. I guess I could tweak the phonegap settings to allow .load() to take place, but I want to see if this is possible using plain html and standard security first**

**NOTE#2: I just realized I can do this successfully (use load()) with phonegap. But I'm leaving this question open if there's a way to do it using file:// on desktop with no security warnings.**

Comment: Why not just put up a server? Setting up a static node.js serv only takes 5 minutes...

Comment: Why don't you use an iframe?

Comment: iframe idea is interesting, please mark as answer

Comment: upload it to a real server OR make a localhost on your machine.. it will solve the problem automatically

Comment: note, iframe is not so good b/c i want to share the context between both pages

Comment: see my 'NOTE:' about webserver in my question

Comment: Doesn't phonegap allow loading local content if the main file is local though? You sure this isn't just a problem when testing on desktop?

Comment: I'm testing this and it will be the fallback, but I really want this to work on the desktop first. Mainly I want to see if this is a limitation with html as a technology or not.

Comment: Well if it works on the device you can always just use a server for testing.

Comment: yes, but again.. looking to see if I can do this with vanilla html and no strings. if there's a hack maybe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `html imports` .
Here is a good explanation about they: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/.

Comment: That says it needs to be CORS enabled though, which the file protocol apparently doesn't support.

Comment: yeah html import has the same security problem as load